# React failed in npm start

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My app was running correctly.

Unfortunately, now I get into trouble even when I create *create-react-app* and run `npm start`.

```sh
// Linux terminal

npm i -g create-react-app // Success
create-react-app app // Success
cd app // Success


npm start // Failed
```

Result command:

```sh
Compiled successfully!

You can now view the app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.42.239:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/amir/.npm/_logs/2020-03-31T22_00_55_044Z-debug.log
```

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: What does it say in the debug log?

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse your server is already running in that port `3000` but you are again trying to run the same server in another terminal tab.